# Pybind11 + nan Node module conflicting

Tags: c++, node.js, cmake, nan, pybind11

```
/usr/include/python3.5m/node.h:19:20: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'PyNode_New'
 PyAPI_FUNC(node *) PyNode_New(int type);
                    ^
/usr/include/python3.5m/node.h:20:17: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'PyNode_AddChild'
 PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyNode_AddChild(node *n, int type,
                 ^
/usr/include/python3.5m/node.h:22:18: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'PyNode_Free'
 PyAPI_FUNC(void) PyNode_Free(node *n);
                  ^
/usr/include/python3.5m/node.h:24:11: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 PyAPI_FUNC(Py_ssize_t) _PyNode_SizeOf(node *n);
           ^
```

I'm getting a lot of errors during **make** command when adding pybind11 to my existing C++ project which uses "nan" node module to interact with node.js.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please consider providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the issue, and provide more context for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/issues/867#issuecomment-529817450) worked for me. It is related to the problem i faced.